# Slick Slider ... don't have the current class to play with

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I want to change the opacity of the current slide but I don't have the class to play with in the HTML...

This is what I see:

```
<div class="g_product__wrapper slick-slide slick-cloned slick-active" data-slick-index="6" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 251px;">
```

... there is no slick-current ...

Any idea will be appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The current slide has the below class

```
.slick-current
```

Or try below if you are targeting all visible slides

```
.slick-active
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see in the HTML, there is no .slick-current class... It seems to be missing... Hummm...

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Center Mode to true and used .slick-center instead of .slick-current.
Did the trick for me.

Thanks!